# Can I use prepaid credit card balance for tier 4 visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

My girlfriend is going to apply for the Doctorate Extension Scheme under Tier 4. The maintenance requirement is £2530 for 28 days. She has two accounts summing up to roughly £2500. She also has a Chinese credit card, which is more like a prepaid card with more or less £1000 equivalent. This is the money she overpaid and can be spent as normal bank account balance.

I am quite paranoid about this because the Tier 4 policy guidance clearly states that "Other accounts or financial instruments such as shares, bonds, overdrafts, ***credit cards*** and pension funds are not acceptable." My girlfriend tends to think that means "credit card (limits)" because that comes right after "overdrafts". She certainly has a point. It is understandable that either credit card limits or overdraft facilities cannot be used as fund proofs.

I found the following question in SE, but it not exactly the same as her case.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/can-i-convince-embassies-to-accept-my-overpaid-credit-card-as-a-proof-of-funds

Does anyone have a certain answer about this matter? Many thanks!

Comment: The question you referenced is about tourist visas, primarily for Schengen.